# How do I include scripts in my Google Apps Script/Google Sheets HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cannot get my Apps Script-based HTML to include any scripts.

My `doGet` function for the `HtmlService` works fine:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myhtmlfilename');
}
```

I seem to get the following whether or not I have any script tags on my HTML file:

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdozY.png)

I have tried storing all of my JavaScript in a separate HTML file with  tags (called `JavaScript.html`) and then including them back into my HTML using force print scriptlets.

My HTML file containing my script tags:

```
<script>
function transferItems(){
google.script.run.test();
}

</script>
```

My function to include the script HTML as a scriptlet, which I have also tried as 'getRawContent' instead of 'evaluate':

```
function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
```

My scriptlet:

```
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

My function in my code.gs, called `test()`:

```
function test() {
alert("This is a test."); 
}
```

My button in my main HTML page through which I am trying to call the `test()` function:

```
<button onClick="transferItems()">Transfer</button>
```

No matter what I try my page ends up displaying those scriptlets as text in the browser.

[displayed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jysxZ.png)

What am I missing?

All of the answers and tutorials I have read are from 2015ish or earlier.
I feel like I am following Google's documentation.

Comment: Look at the HTMLService's createTemplateFromFile: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets

Comment: Thank you for responding, Chris. I did read that article before I posted my question. I must be implementing it incorrectly, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone right now. I'll see what I can do when I get back.

Comment: Can you post the portion of your code with the HTMLSevice and UI?

Comment: Chris, thank you for your time in looking at this. I edited my post to include more information. Not sure if it's everything you need.

Comment: You probably don't have an `include` function in a "gs" file.  It's a common mistake.  If that isn't the problem, then show your include function.  `function include(fileName) {var h; h = HtmlService.createOutputFromFile(fileName).getContent(); return h;}`

Comment: Thank you Sandy i just edited to show my include function. Would changing it to match yours make a difference? I started out trying it as '.creatOutputFromFile', but have started trying it as a template instead. In other words, do I need to create a variable and then return it, or can I just return the whole HtmlService...getContent();?

Comment: I tried it your way, @Sandy. I am still getting the entire scriptlet displayed as text in my browser. Any thoughts? Where in my html should I be placing the scriptlet?

Comment: Exactly @MattW what I get is the include

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the `<?...?>` scriptlets in your HTML file when you evaluate with the HTMLService you **need** to use `createTemplateFromFile()` otherwise they will be treated as plain text. The `createOutputFromFile()` won't work for evaluating the script tags.

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myhtmlfilename').evaluate();
}
```

**EDIT:** Your include doesn't need to evaluate those `<?  ?>` scriptlets. So it just needs the be like this:

```
function include(filename) { 
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Using my phone to answer so the code might not be perfect.

Comment: That's almost it! It is no longer displaying the scriptlet as text. It also must be working as intended, because when I click the button, the error i get in the console is 'alert is not defined'. So it is including the second html file with my script containing the transferItems() function correctly. however, once google.script.run attempts to call the test() function, I am getting that alert.

Comment: I wouldn't except the alert to work as it's being called from outside the html JavaScript... But as I'm answering on my phone I can't test... I'll be home in about an hour and I can test a bit more.

Comment: I tried it using a different function other than alert(), and it worked! Thank you so much, @Chris W. I am curious as to why the alert() function did not work though. Isn't that a standard javaScript function? Or is it because I'm calling it from within App Script and not directly in my html? -- ok you answered that already. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer worked for me but I also wanted to add that you can perform the include logic inline in the template rather than making a separate `include()` function. For example ...

```
<html>
<head>
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ClientScript').getContent(); ?>
</head>
```

The only issue I've had is the editor doesn't work as well with JavaScript *in* HTML; I was really hoping I could use this method to include `.gs` files to re-use functionality between the client and server.

Here's a page for reference which explains separating out CSS and JavaScript files using this method: https://yagisanatode.com/2018/04/15/google-apps-script-how-to-create-javascript-and-css-files-for-a-sidebar-project-in-google-apps-script/