# How to process scriptlets in my HTML file instead of them showing plain-text?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I can't figure it out how I can get the HTML to process the extension/caller (scriptlets) that look like this `<?= var data = getData()?>`. Here is my script [code link](https://script.google.com/d/1ZbXqSJ_NBEna7L7i3J7zu2iIO7BpcE-jfnzU8LtRCLZ3-tykAVQd8pGC/edit?usp=sharing).

Please check out  my error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48844833/1691677):

If you have the `<?...?>` scriptlets in your HTML file when you evaluate with the HTMLService you **need** to use `createTemplateFromFile()` otherwise they will be treated as plain text. The `createHTMLOutputFromFile()` won't work for evaluating the script tags.

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
```

You should take a look at the [HTMLService best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates) for async loading.

Comment: is there a way to make the web responsive? i used bootstrap on this. Or ill make my own css?

Comment: @MOO Definitely, I use jQuery and bootstrap in many of my Web Apps to create responsive pages. Take a look at the [Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) page on how to use `google.script.run`.

Comment: So all your html tag is made by javascript?

Comment: Nope, only some, I use `google.script.run` ([more here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)) to call functions in my main, server-side Code.gs file that returns data and updates fields using jQuery on the Web App page without reloading it. The main structure of the page is in HTML and already there but some elements are updated and changed later.

Comment: I dont undertand how you made your code. Can u give an examples of your code? Maybe your coding style ill get some tips and understand the steps on how you do/make a web app

Comment: You using `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()` than the `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)`?

Comment: Which is i will use when i need bootstrap? `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()` or `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)`?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Re-read my answer. `createTemplateFromFile()` is only needed to process `<?...?>` scriptlets.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out with this issue. Scriplets doesnt works with HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('XXX') function.

so before returning out HtmlOutput, use ; **append method** :

Ex of script which worked :

```
function doGet(e){
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('pageone');

  htmlOutput.append(include('frontendScript'))
  
  return htmlOutput
}

function include(scriptName){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(scriptName).getContent();
}
```

Secondly another(auxiliary ) function can be defined which handles template  & return templates content . Then in the doGet function we will call this auxiliary function using createHtmlOutput(auxFun()):

```
function auxFun(){
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pageone');
  return htmlOutput.evaluate().getContent();
}

function doGet(e){
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(auxFun());
  htmlOutput.setTitle('my title');
  htmlOutput.addMetaTag('viewport','width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

  //htmlOutput.append(include('fmyfrontendScript'));
// continue using scriplets : <?!= include('myfrontendScript') ?>
  
  return htmlOutput;
}

function include(scriptName){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(scriptName).getContent();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).