# Google Script Short Tags displaying on webpage

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build a google web app that will need to have multiple pages.  I found [Mogsdad's solution to that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script/16697525#16697525), and am trying to implement that.  However, the short tag is displaying on my page, as opposed to running in the background.  For simplicity purposes, here's a really short example of what I'm seeing.

testfile.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Source = testfile.html</h1>
    <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=my2'> <input type='button' name='button' value='my2.html'></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is an image of the webpage that is generated from that html.

[image]

As you can see, the text inside the short open/close tags is actually displaying, as opposed to being run.  I've done a lot of searching on this, and found a number of things related to php (which I know uses a similar tag to do the same thing), and making sure the php.ini is set correctly.  But I haven't seen anything to help when it's google apps script where the short open tag is displaying.  Anyone else run into this?  Any thoughts on where the issue here is?

Comment: Scriptlet evaluation requires you to call `evaluate()` on an `HtmlTemplate` object, to produce your `HtmlOutput`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process scriptlets in my HTML file instead of them showing plain-text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928877/how-to-process-scriptlets-in-my-html-file-instead-of-them-showing-plain-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doGet()` function needs to look like this:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('testfile')
      .evaluate();
}
```

You don't need the first scriptlet at all.  You can change the scriptlet in the href attribute to:

```
<a href="<?= getScriptUrl() ?>?page=my2"> <input type='button' name='button' value='my2.html'></a>
```

You can see the documentation at:

[Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#standard_scriptlets)

Comment: That worked; thank you very much.  It's always those little things that get in my way.